# Creating Cognitive Search index in Databricks: connection.HTTPSConnection Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, azure-cognitive-search

I am attempting to create a Cognitive Search Index in Databricks. I'm using the following as a guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-get-started-python

When I execute the following code I get the error:

```
<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fb54030e1c0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

I feel this is a common error, but I can't find any solutions when I do a Google Search.

The Databricks Runtime: 9.1 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.1.2, Scala 2.12)

My Connection is as follows:

```
service_name = "https://myazuredemo.search.windows.net"
admin_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

index_name = "hotels-quickstart"

# Create an SDK client
endpoint = "https://{}.search.windows.net/".format(service_name)
admin_client = SearchIndexClient(endpoint=endpoint,
                     index_name=index_name,
                     credential=AzureKeyCredential(admin_key))

search_client = SearchClient(endpoint=endpoint,
                     index_name=index_name,
                     credential=AzureKeyCredential(admin_key))
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is here:

```py
service_name = "https://myazuredemo.search.windows.net"
endpoint = "https://{}.search.windows.net/".format(service_name)
```

it will give you following URL:

```
https://https://myazuredemo.search.windows.net.search.windows.net/
```

so either set `service_name` to `myazuredemo` or just set `endpoint` to `https://myazuredemo.search.windows.net`